# Velocity mapping template to join path parameters with request body in API Gateway

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, velocity, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to return the following JSON object:

```
{
"confirmationNumber": "TESTABC",
"clientExternalId": "testymctesterson@gmail.com",
"leftVoiceMessage": true,
"preferredStylist": true,
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"phoneNumber": "(123) 456-7890",
"smsEnabled": "true"
}
```

Confirmation number is the only path parameter. I want to join the path parameter with the request body by looping through and returning the key/value pairs in the body so I can use one template. This template almost gets me there, but it returns the boolean values as strings:

```
{
#foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end,
#foreach($key in $input.path('$').keySet())
"$key": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.path('$').get($key))"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
}
```

I'd like to do something like this, but then you get an extra set of brackets around the request body after transformation:

```
{
#foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end,
$input.json('$')
}
```

Is there a way to get the desired JSON object without doing string manipulation on JSON or hard coding the keys?

Comment: Can you show us the results you get for clarity? Also, in the desired output you show, there are two `true` and one `"true"` value, is it normal?

Comment: I would suggest to use Lambda proxy integration on API Gateway and implement the routing logic inside the Lambda function, then it will be much easier.